# Android ActionBar Navigation Tabs looks differ in phones and tablets

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is it possible for ActionBar Navigation Tabs to be displayed same on both phones and tablets?

See images for phone and tablets below:

**PHONE:**
[image: Phone Image]

**TABLET:**
[image: Tablet]

The Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) states "...when the screen is wide enough the tabs appear in the action bar alongside the action buttons...". **We don't want them to appear in ActionBar**. Any solutions?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.strava application also does this. Don't know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ActionBar` tabs are created by the [`ScrollingTabContainerView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ScrollingTabContainerView.java). The [`ActionBarView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ActionBarView.java),  the actual `View` for the `ActionBar`, contains a method [`ActionBarView.setEmbeddedTabView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ActionBarView.java#L364) which is essentially responsible for the placement of the tabs either below or embedded in the `ActionBar`.

When the `ActionBar` is [initialized in `Activity`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L1912), it uses the [`ActionBarPolicy`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/ActionBarPolicy.java#L55) to determine when to use the embedded tabs based on a `boolean` value that's defined as [`true` in the system's resources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/bools.xml#L22), but [`false` in portrait mode](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values-port/bools.xml#L18). So, upon this initialization [`ActionBarImpl.setHasEmbeddedTabs`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java#L217) is called to determine where to place the tabs. And also, as the docs state:

> ...when the screen is wide enough the tabs appear in the action bar
>   alongside the action buttons

**So how do I stop it from embedding the tabs?**

Seems like you have two choices here and one is clearly, at least to me, better than the other.

1. You can use reflection to invoke `ActionBarImpl.setHasEmbeddedTabs` and set it to always be `false`. You need to use reflection because `ActionBarImpl` is an internal class and there is no public `ActionBar` method to indicate when to embed tabs.
2. You can stop using the `ActionBar.Tab` API and switch to an alternative, [like Google's `SlidingTabLayout`](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/X8fg63wK6S8). This one will require you to use a `ViewPager`, which is usually is a nice plus when using tabs anyway and you may even already be using it.

Here are examples for both:

**Using reflection**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    // Implement your tabs
    ...
    try {
        final Class<?> clazz = actionBar.getClass();
        final Method embedTabs = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
        embedTabs.invoke(actionBar, false);
    } catch (final Exception ignored) {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```

**Reflection results**

[image: Example]

**Switching from the fixed tabs to scrollable tabs**

To use Google's `SlidingTabLayout`, you'll need to copy over two classes into your project. The classes you need are:

- [SlidingTabLayout](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html)
- [SlidingTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabStrip.html)

An example layout implementing the `SlidingTabLayout` would looks this like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <your_path_to.SlidingTabLayout
          android:id="@+id/slidingTabs"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/viewPager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

After inflating the layout and initializing the `SlidingTabLayout` using `View.findViewById`, you call `SlidingTabLayout.setViewPager` to bind the `ViewPager` to the tabs.

[Check out Google's example for a full project](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)

**Scrollable tab results**

Scrollable tabs are used in several of Google's app, like the Play Store and Play Music. For a short video demonstrating them, if you're unfamiliar, [check out the Android design docs on tabs](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html).

**Conclusion**

In short, I would recommend using scrollable tabs rather than fixed tabs (at least in landscape mode), if you don't want them to be embedded.