# Android - action bar tabs stick left

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have 3 tabs in my app using android action bar, the tabs look good on phones but when it lunches on tablet, the tabs stick to left of screen and right side is empty, how can I set tabs on center of action bar for tablets like phones?
I found same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093404/android-actionbar-navigation-tabs-looks-differ-in-phones-and-tablets) but there is no answer, it has pictures that may help you to understand my problem better.

Comment: I think posting the XML's would be very helpfull

Comment: @user3511155 I answered the original post you linked to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ActionBar Navigation Tabs looks differ in phones and tablets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093404/android-actionbar-navigation-tabs-looks-differ-in-phones-and-tablets)

Comment: I used your first way and added this lines to my main activity but there is no difference, still tabs stick to right. `try {
        final Class<?> abi = Class.forName("com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl");
        final Method embedTabs = abi.getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", new Class[] {
                boolean.class
        });
        embedTabs.invoke(actionBar, false);
    } catch (final Exception ignored) {
        // Nothing to do
    }`