# Force actionbar tabs to sit on actionbar in portrait mode, just like in landscape mode?

Tags: android

Is there a way to force my tabs to sit on the actionbar when in portrait mode, just like they do automatically in landscape mode?

The code for setting up the tabs is just the new project setup code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

for (int i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
    actionBar.addTab(
      actionBar.newTab().setIcon(...));
}
```

The tabs each show an icon and are very small, so should fit across in portrait mode on most devices without having to sit on their own tab bar.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to use reflection. [I wrote a post recently on doing the opposite of this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22969982/420015), so you'd pass `true` instead of `false` when you call `invoke` to force them into the `ActionBar` in portrait mode. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/40sON1i.png)

Comment: Oh too bad they didn't leave an option for us developers. Do you know if it's possible to have the tabs expand to take up the available width on the actionbar? In your screenshot it looks like they're take up only as much width as needed.